# Left join two tables and get the count of records in the second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables the first table with a list of modules and the second module mapping table.

I need to fetch all the records from the first 'modules' table along with the count of the corresponding occurrence of the module mapping id in the second mapping table which has role_id=25

I have used the below code

```
SELECT 
  `m`.`title`, 
  `m`.`id`, 
  CASE WHEN map.role_id =25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as counter 
FROM `z6wpx_modules` as `m` 
LEFT JOIN `z6wpx_users_module_map` as `map` ON `map`.`module_id` = `m`.`id` 
GROUP by m.id
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: share your sql on fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()`. For example:

```
SELECT 
  `m`.`title`, 
  `m`.`id`, 
   COUNT(*) as counter
FROM `z6wpx_modules` as `m` 
LEFT JOIN `z6wpx_users_module_map` as `map` ON `map`.`module_id` = `m`.`id` 
WHERE map.role_id = 25
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
```

Or you can use `SUM()` function to calculate count by all roles

```
SELECT 
  `m`.`title`, 
  `m`.`id`, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN map.role_id = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as counter 
FROM `z6wpx_modules` as `m` 
LEFT JOIN `z6wpx_users_module_map` as `map` ON `map`.`module_id` = `m`.`id`   
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
```

Comment: Maxim , we are almost there but we will get only the matching 2 records , as we are using where caluse. we need to get the unmatched records also from the first table

Comment: @AnoopPS It only count the modules row count, not the corrosponding map table count.

Comment: i need to get all rows from the first table along with number of occurence of module_id in second row

Comment: maxim it works , thanks maxim ;) .. thanks for your help. keep in touch

Comment: i have also  used case but a problem occurs with duplication of same records

Comment: @MaximFedorov Yeah, :)

Answer (score 0):

Subquery will help

```
SELECT 
`m`.`title`, 
`m`.`id`, 
(select COUNT(*) from `z6wpx_users_module_map` as `subMap` where 
`subMap`.`module_id`=`m`.`id` ) as counter
FROM `z6wpx_modules` as `m` 
LEFT JOIN `z6wpx_users_module_map` as `map` ON `map`.`module_id` = `m`.`id` 
WHERE map.role_id = 25
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
```